# php-mysql error while inserting into table

Tags: php, mysql

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: YOu inserting through PHP or Mysql? And as Andy said, it helps to know the code. Check your spelling(right table name, "" and not '', quotation mark) since it's syntax

Answer (score 0):

Yeah... it really helps to see the query to decipher it.  From what you have though, it appears, the double-quote " character is not used in mysql.  If you are dealing with strings, they are typically wrapped with 'single-quotes'.  I'd check that first. if still a problem, then post your query for others to help.

Comment: That's not a double-quote, though. it's two single quotes.

Comment: Then, yeah, lets see the query to help decipher it as it correlates to the error